# How to store the output of a command that has already gone throgh pipeline

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying store the first word of the second line of the output of a command as a variable

I have tried putting the whole thing inside of () with a $ in front of it,it doesn't work

```
containerID= docker ps | awk 'END { print }' | { read first rest ; echo $first ; }

echo $containerID
echo $containerID
```

I expected it to spit back the containerID variable twice, however it only spits it back once.  in troubleshooting I found that "echo $first" is why it is outputting anything.  This implies that it isn't storing anything in the containerID variable, why?

Comment: If you want the first word of the 2nd line: `awk 'NR==2{print $1}'`

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(...)` to capture a command's output. Don't put any space around the equal sign.

```
containerID=$(docker ps | awk 'END { print }' | { read first rest ; echo $first ; })
```

Simpler:

```
containerID=$(docker ps | awk 'END {print $1}')
```